# Iterating over a dataframe changes the column structure

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I've seen many posts highlighting this behavior with iterrows(), however we're observing it with .columns and .dtypes.

There are two key pieces of code here

#1. A simple for loop iterating over the dataframe

```
for col in df.columns:
    print("hello")

#A line of code that performs a join with the dataframe

files = target.join(df, primaryKeys, 'inner').select(col("filepath").alias("filepath1")).distinct()
```

Without the for loop this works fine. However, when the above for loop is uncommented this fails with 'str' object is not callable. If we try using

```
for col in df.dtypes:
    print("hello")
```

it fails with

> 'tuple' object is not callable.

I also tried

```
select_expr = [
    col(c).cast("smallint") if t == "tinyint)" else col(c) for c, t in df4.dtypes
]
df4 = df4.select(*select_expr)
```

which failed with

> 'str' object is not callable.

Why is the act of iterating over the for loop causing the join to fail? Does the iteration somehow change the underlying dataframe? I've seen it happen with iterrows before, but there are plenty of code samples using columns/dtypes as I showed above that work just fine.

Comment: Probably because you defined `col` as some list of col names, but then overwrite it with the variable (that stores a tuple or string) you use when iterating

Comment: @ALollz You're exactly correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `import pyspark.sql.functions as F` and `F.col(c)` instead of `col(c)`.

Inside the for loop, `col` is replaced with the iteration variable `col` in `for col in df.columns`, which is a string.

When you write `col(c)`, you're calling `col` with an argument `c`, but `col` is a string variable, so you got `str object is not callable` error.

Comment: Well here's what I'm missing there, why does it work correctly without the for loop?

Comment: because without the for loop, `col` remains the spark sql function.

Comment: but inside the for loop, `col` is overwritten by the iteration variable `for col in df.columns`

Comment: Yup, you got it

Comment: I want to die, thanks for the help. I've been working with node for the last year, forgot that contextual functions could be overwritten like that

Comment: As a good practice, avoid using function names like `col` as iteration variables. I'd use something like `c`. Also I'd suggest using `import pyspark.sql.functions as F` and `F.col`.

Comment: Right, so with import pyspark.sql.functions as F you're protecting your functions from overwriting

Comment: yes, unless you use `F` as a variable... which is much less likely to happen.